# cinnamon, как убрать ошибку: Clutter-WARNING lutter-actor.c:10052: Actor 'StScrollBar' tried to allocate a size...?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, cinnamon

Установил ubuntu 19.10. Через не которое время решил установить новый рабочий стол cinnamon. После установки все работало, отлично. Не давно появилась проблема, запустил double commander и увидел такую картинку:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

появились белые полосы и белая подложка на основных компонентах, и не важно работаю я с cinnamon или перехожу на родной unity от ubuntu.

В корневой папке пользователя в файл .xsession-errors каждую секунду пишется ошибка:

---

(cinnamon:16676): Clutter-WARNING **: 18:32:43.369: clutter-actor.c:10052: Actor 'StScrollBar' tried to allocate a size of -6,00 x 6,00

(cinnamon:16676): Clutter-WARNING **: 18:32:43.369: clutter-actor.c:10052: Actor 'StBoxLayout' tried to allocate a size of -6,00 x 0,00

(cinnamon:16676): Clutter-WARNING **: 18:32:43.373: clutter-actor.c:10052: Actor 'StScrollBar' tried to allocate a size of -6,00 x 6,00

(cinnamon:16676): Clutter-WARNING **: 18:32:43.373: clutter-actor.c:10052: Actor 'StBoxLayout' tried to allocate a size of -6,00 x 0,00

---

Как решить подобную проблему в сети не нашел, так же мне не понятно от куда и как это проблема могла появиться....

Спасибо за помощь!

Answer (score 1):

Плохо искали... Вон даже багрепорт болтается.
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/kubuntu-meta/+bug/1734998

У самого такие проблемы были на убунте кде редакции новой, в итоге долго возился с отключением компонентов - помогло отключение скроллбара(можно сделать глобальное, а можно на пробу под конкретный профиль) - т.к. этот баг, видимо, из-за оверлейных полос прокрутки, будь они неладны.
Может в циане чего другое виновато, но вообще похоже что просто напортачили, и надо фиксов ждать. Ну или решать самому проблему, играясь с настройками этих баров, на край можно вообще удалить overlay-scrollbar

```
gsettings set com.canonical.desktop.interface scrollbar-mode normal
```

может помочь, если не поможет обратно вернуть можно

```
gsettings reset com.canonical.desktop.interface scrollbar-mode
```

*я в итоге на манджару окончательно перебежал*

Comment: видел этот report, там речь идет не о скролбаре... хотя проблема почти идентичная.... команда "gsettings set com.canonical.desktop.interface scrollbar-mode normal" не работает, пишет:  "Схема «com.canonical.desktop.interface» отсутствует" .... сижу разбираюсь дальше...

Comment: а удалить модуль оверлея плохой вариант?
double commander у вас qt, или gtk? т.к. на кути обычно автозамена на стандартный скроллбар из 11 бунты, возможно как раз в этом и ошибка

Comment: Сам double commander, удалял, переустанавливал не помогает, с оверлейм не сталкивался, только после Вашего поста начал руками пробовать и разбираться... Если подскажите как удалить для double commander буду признателен!

Comment: `LIBOVERLAY_SCROLLBAR=foo <команда>` с вот этой командой в консоли можно работу проверить, а отключить `LIBOVERLAY_SCROLLBAR=0 <команда>`

Если работает - можно для всего отключить, запихнув `export LIBOVERLAY_SCROLLBAR=0` в ~/.xprofile

Comment: _у меня сейчас убунты не имеется для тестов, напишите если не сработает(хотя вроде как правильно), если что можно просто в `dconf-editor` выключить элемент убунты-оверлей-скроллбарс, перезагрузиться и их не будет... Т.к. если это забаговали в новом релизе, то лучше отключить этот модуль_

Comment: LIBOVERLAY_SCROLLBAR=0 к сожалению, команда не на что не влияет, если делать под sudo то пишет что не найдена. Установил dconf-editor, но не понял где это можно отключить. У меня при запуске этой утилиты есть две subfolder "seahorse" и "update-manager"... посмотрел их содержимое, и не совсем понятно где можно этот оверлай отрубить...(((

Comment: Обратил внимание в .xsession-errors теперь ошибки не пишется, но проблема с double commnaderom осталась... в любом случае спасибо за помощь!

Comment: `org > gnome(в вашем случае циан) > Desktop > Applications` путь должен быть такой... И там, собственно, отключается. Или в gconf-editor

возможно ещё отключается `GTK_OVERLAY_SCROLLING=0 <команда>`, или можно в убунту твиак отключить `sudo apt-get install unity-tweak-tool` и там в systems->scrollbars отключить. Есть [ещё](https://github.com/tualatrix/ubuntu-tweak)

Comment: эх - это капец....))) Такого пути нет :-( "org > gnome(в вашем случае циан) > Desktop > Applications", проходим "Desktop", а дальше идут различные подпункты, более или менее созвучное нашел default-applications, но там нет параметра со скролом. Установил gconf-editor в дереве есть apps и shemas но внутри они по сути все пустые.... дальше установил unity-tweak-tool, у меня русская локализация и поэтому интуитивно вроде нашел, где речь идет о скроле, но блин он не сохраняет изменения ( и под sudo тоже) .... не хочется из за это проблемы менять дистрибутив....